# Run .net 4 webapplication as virtual directory under under 3.5 webapplication on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, iis-6, virtual-directory

I am running a .Net 3.5 webapp on IIS6 . I now have a .Net4 webapp that i need to run as a virtual directory under the main 3.5 webapp.

I have made a 4.0 application pool, created the virtual directory and set the app to use the 4.0 application pool. The 4.0 webapp has it's own web.config which is in it's virtual directory.

I am getting this error:

```
The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the Web.config file.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the Web.config file.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ConfigurationErrorsException: The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the Web.config file.]


System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.ValidateCompilerVersionFor40AndAbove(String compilerVersion) +235
System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.ValidateCompilerVersionFor40AndAbove() +76
System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.InitializeTargetFrameworkName() +101
System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.EnsureFrameworkNamesInitialized() +149
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +204
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +246
System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +350

[HttpException (0x80004005): The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the <compilation> element of the Web.config file.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9013676
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +258


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

in my 4.0 web.config the compiler version IS set to 4.0.

Comment: Any reason why you can't update the site to 4.0 but run it in 3.5 compatibility mode?

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck with this.  I'm stuck with the same problem (although I'm using IIS7)? Cheers.

Comment: Just checking-but did you change the asp.net version in the virtual directory? Also,We had this weird problem when we upgrading a 3.5 to 4 app on a site like yours, we ended up creating a totally new virtual directory and that solved the issue. But from your description, I wasn't sure if it was an upgrade or not.